# Why is this query giving two different results?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, inner-join

I am querying from 3 Tables and 1 View

**Table 1 = 'information'**

```
id          int(11) PK
name        varchar(45)
industry    int(11)
...alot more columns.
```

**Table 2 = 'industry'**

```
id          int(11) PK
type        varchar(45)
```

**View 1 = 'event_entrys'**

```
id          int(11)
eventName   varchar(45)
hraScreened tinyint
hraBmi      decimal(10,2)
hraWaist    decimal(10,2)
gender      tinyint
...a lot more columns.
```

**View(of `event_entrys`) = '569e98bd-eb23-11e3-b215-00059a3c7800'**

```
id          int(11)
eventName   varchar(45)
hraScreened tinyint
hraBmi      decimal(10,2)
hraWaist    decimal(10,2)
gender      tinyint
...a lot more columns.
```

**value in view.eventName is inserted from information.name.**

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `event_entrys` AS ee WHERE ee.`hraScreened` = 1 AND ee.`hraBmi` > 0 AND ee.`hraBmi` NOT BETWEEN 18.5 AND 25 AND ee.`hraWaist` > IF(ee.`gender` = 0, 102, 88) AND 
(SELECT `industry` FROM `information` WHERE `name` = ee.`clientName`) IN (SELECT inf1.`industry` FROM `information` AS inf1 INNER JOIN `569e98bd-eb23-11e3-b215-00059a3c7800` AS ee2 ON inf1.`name` = ee2.`clientName` GROUP BY inf1.`industry`))
```

Above query I am using in a long mysql procedure.

But the above query returns 0 for some time in the start and after executing it a couple of times it starts returning 28(any number for instance but not 0)

When ran separately this query is true for 28 records in my condition

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `569e98bd-eb23-11e3-b215-00059a3c7800` AS ee WHERE ee.`hraScreened` = 1 AND ee.`hraBmi` > 0 AND ee.`hraBmi` NOT BETWEEN 18.5 AND 25
```

ee.`clientName` = 'POLMED MEDICAL SCHEME'
ee2.`clientName` = 'POLMED MEDICAL SCHEME'

When ran separately this query returns integer 17

```
SELECT `industry` FROM `information` WHERE `name` = ee.`clientName`
```

When ran separately this query returns integer 17

```
SELECT inf1.`industry` FROM `information` AS inf1 INNER JOIN `569e98bd-eb23-11e3-b215-00059a3c7800` AS ee2 ON inf1.`name` = ee2.`clientName` GROUP BY inf1.`industry`
```

I have tried a lot but I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong...
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to work out your main query.  It seems to be checking that the industry it finds from the information table for a record on ee exists as a matching record from when joining information against ee (which will always be true). Or am I missing something

Comment: Yes, it will be always true. And the record formed via JOIN will always contain that industry which the previous query is asking for. Hope i answered your question. And thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recoding you long query to use a join, and thus avoid trying to check the result of one correlated sub query is in the result of another sub query (which I have never seen done before):-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 569e98bd-eb23-11e3-b215-00059a3c7800 AS ee 
INNER JOIN information inf ON inf.name = ee.clientName
WHERE ee.hraScreened = 1 
AND ee.hraBmi > 0 
AND ee.hraBmi NOT BETWEEN 18.5 AND 25 
AND ee.hraWaist > IF(ee.gender = 0, 102, 88) 
AND inf.industry 
IN 
(
    SELECT inf1.industry 
    FROM information AS inf1 
    INNER JOIN 569e98bd-eb23-11e3-b215-00059a3c7800 AS ee2 
    ON inf1.name = ee2.clientName 
    GROUP BY inf1.industry
)
```

Reading this it seems for a record on ee it gets the industry by finding the row on the information table where the name is the clientName from ee. It then checks if that resulting industry is in the result of a sub query.

However that sub query is just joining the information table and ee again, with the same join condition but less restrictions on the rows of ee.

As far as I can see this will always be found, so checking it is in the results of the sub query is redundant.

The query could just be written as:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 569e98bd-eb23-11e3-b215-00059a3c7800 AS ee 
INNER JOIN information inf ON inf.name = ee.clientName
WHERE ee.hraScreened = 1 
AND ee.hraBmi > 0 
AND ee.hraBmi NOT BETWEEN 18.5 AND 25 
AND ee.hraWaist > IF(ee.gender = 0, 102, 88)
```

Comment: Sorry man, i just edited the question could you please update your answer accordingly ? Tx

Comment: Afraid I can't see any edits. I can't see why your query would give different results, hence my suggestion was to simplify the query and hopefully spot something. The only thing I can think of is that your first sub query brings back more than 1 row, but I would expect that to cause an error.

Comment: looks like your simple query solved my problem as i'am getting correct values, but then i have had this feeling before :D tx btw